# ASP.NET partial view validation fails

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, partial-views

I'm having problems with validating my partial view. My Index view is being made by few partial views. One of those views, _Contact, is being used so that users can submit to upcoming event. I want to enable the check if somebody already submitted to the event with entered e-mail. It all works fine, but the problem is that it does not show the message about the failed submission(it fails the validation on server side, but wont show the error to the user). Here is my code:

```
 Index:
...
 @if(ViewBag.Competitor==null)
{@Html.Partial("_Contact", new CompetitorViewModel())}else
                          {
@Html.Partial("_Contact",(CompetitorViewModel)ViewBag.Competitor)
}
...

 _Contact:
 @model Models.CompetitorViewModel

 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")">     </script>


<section id="contact">
    <div id="contact-us" class="parallax">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="heading text-center col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">


                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-form wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitStudent", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "main-contact-form" }))
                        {
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                            <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                         @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.firstName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder="Ime"})
                                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.firstName)
                                   </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.lastName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder="Prezime"})
                                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.lastName)
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.eMail, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder="Email Adresa"})
                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.eMail)   
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.collegeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Colleges)   
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">

                                 <input type="submit" value="Prijavi me" class="btn-submit" />
                            </div>

                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="contact-info wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/#contact-->
```

main.js:

```
 var form = $('#main-contact-form');
 form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: '/Home/SubmitStudent',
        data: $('#main-contact-form').serializeArray(),
    cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Your request is being sent...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
}).
    success(function(data){


        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for submitting to this event</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    }).
        complete(function ()
    {
            $("#main-contact-form").each(function () { $.data($(this)[0], 'validator', false); });
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#main-contact-form");
    })

});
```

HomeController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitStudent(CompetitorViewModel c)
    {
        var colleges = _db.colleges.Distinct().ToList();
        ViewBag.Colleges = new SelectList(colleges, "id", "Name"); 

             if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Competitor = c;

        }
        else
        {
            var competitors = _db.competitors;


            foreach (Competitor c1 in competitors)
            {
                if (c1.eMail == c.eMail)
                     {
                         ModelState.AddModelError("c.eMail", "That E-mail is already registered to this event.");
                         ViewBag.Competitor = c;
                         return View("Index");
                     }
            }


            DCCollege college = (DCCollege)_db.colleges.Find(c.collegeId);
            Competitor competitor = new Competitor();
            competitor.firstName = c.firstName;
            competitor.lastName = c.lastName;
            competitor.eMail = c.eMail;
            competitor.college = college;

            competitors.Add(competitor);
            _db.Save();
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me. I'm struggling with this for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly looked through the code. I think you don't see the validation message because you add it to ModelState but then you don't pass the model to the view.

Comment: I do pass a model to the View. I put it in a ViewBag and in Index view i pass it to the partial _Contact as a model. I also tried to return Partial view directly from the controller, didn't work either.

Comment: Yes, but ModelState isn't related to ViewBag.You pass to "Index" ModelState, but "Contacts" gets only model from ViewBag. Sorry, I don't know how to pass ModelsState to PartialView, maybe it is possible, but I don't think so. The easiest solution for you - add error message to ViewBag too, and show it manually (<p>@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</p>). But it is really bad. I suggest you think about changing logic, architecture. As example, you can validate email using another little request to the server, HTTP GET.